# php how to match @@MESSAGE@@

Tags: php, regex, string

If I have something like this

```
This is Before HELLO

@@MESsage@@

@@MESSAGE@@

Hello @@MESSAGE@@ssd

This is After
```

how can I match only @@MESSAGE@@ ? I tried this and it does not work

```
preg_replace('/\b@@MESSAGE@@\b/u', xxx, xxxy);
```

Comment: [`/@@MESSAGE@@/i`](http://rubular.com/r/WztkD5J0zL) ? You need to use case insensitive since it seems your text is not all equal.

Comment: You have 'something like this'. Please post exactly what you have, and then we can possibly help.

Comment: Do you want to replace every occurrence of @@MeSeAgE@@ or just the uppercase version? Do you also want to match the one followed by ssd?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem are the word boundaries `\b`. They match between word and non-word characters, where a word character is a letter, digit or underscore. Because `@` is not a word character, you require it to be surrounded by those, instead of the opposite. Use a non-word boundary instead:

```
preg_replace('/\B@@MESSAGE@@\B/', $replacement, $input);
```

No need for the `u` modifier by the way.

[Working demo.](http://ideone.com/BvFsZO)

Answer (score 2):

To replace *every* occurrence use:

```
preg_replace('/@@message@@/i', xxx, xxxy);
```

To replace *every* @@MESSAGE@@ in all caps use:

```
preg_replace('/@@MESSAGE@@/', xxx, xxxy);
```

To replace *only* @@MESSAGE@@ by itself use

```
preg_replace('/\B@@MESSAGE@@\B/', xxx, xxxy);
```

If the last case is the one you're looking for, then please accept [m.buettner's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17375214/911182) since that's where I got it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this to be sure to have white characters around your target:

```
preg_replace('~(?:^|\s)\K@@MESSAGE@@(?=\s|$)~', $replacement, $subject);
```